# Setting a method to a default value for unset variables

Tags: php

```
class Test {
    public function test1($var = 'not set'){
        echo $var;
    }
}

$test_ob = new Test();

$test_ob->test1($var); // echo not set

$var = "Hello world";
$test_ob->test1($var); // echo Hello world
```

> **Notice**:  Undefined variable: var in **[......]** on line **9**

I want to be able to pass a unset variable as a parameter, and set it to *not set*.

But it seems that this is not possible... anyone have any ideas?

Comment: There isn't really any *good* way to do it. You can change the argument to a reference which will create it with a null value if it doesn't exist but this is usually considered bad practice. Or you just need to check if your variables exist before using them.

Comment: `if(!$test_ob->test1($var)){ $var = "Hello world";
}`

Comment: @Fred-ii- if `$var` is not set wouldn't that still throw a notice error because it is used in the if expression.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn No. It (my test) echo'ed "Hello world", if that's what the OP's looking to get as a result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @JonathanKhun said, "There's really no good way to do this".  The best I can recommend is a helper function that provides the default-if-not-set behavior, and use that as a wrapper into the functions for which you want this behavior.

```
<?php

function default_if_not_set(&$value = '') {
    return $value;
}

function test($foo) {
    echo "[$foo]" . PHP_EOL;
}

$bar = 'I am bar';
test($bar); // echoes "[I am bar]"

test(default_if_not_set($bar)); // also echoes "[I am bar]"

test($baz); // emits a warning, echoes "[]" -- this is the case you don't want

test(default_if_not_set($baz)); // echoes "[]"
```

The use of `default_if_not_set` as a wrapper gets around the warning, through a pass-by-reference default.  This is at best a trick, and should be considered some form of obfuscatory magic.

Consider perhaps either of these alternate approach, which are a bit more self documenting:

```
<?php
isset($baz) && test($baz);
test(isset($baz) ? $baz : ($baz = 'default'));
```

Comment: in the `default_if_not_set` function you would probably want to include a second argument to set as the default value if the variable is not set. Also, if the variable is not set, it's value will be null, not an empty string. So you should test for is_null($var) and set a default value. Also, like I said above. This is really bad practice. if I called `default_if_not_set($_GET['foo'])` it will actually create `$_GET['foo']` with a `null` value. Now foreach looping over `$_GET` will loop over this unexpected key.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone else has this question, this is how I did it using @bishop answer

```
class Test {
    public function test1($var){
        echo $var;
    }
}

$test_ob = new Test();

$test_ob->test1( (isset($var)?$var:'not set') ); // echo not set

$var = "Hello world";
$test_ob->test1($var); // echo Hello world
```